# separating data in an array for display in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4.5, mxml, flexbuilder

I'm new to flex/flash builder, i need to read in data from a text document, then slice it into pieces i set out in my custom class.

all of this so far worked

```
var theCustomer:Customer=new Customer(name,address,phoneNo,comment,custNo);
custArray.addItem(theCustomer);
```

So now what i want to do is display only the name from each entry of the array into a combobox - and then on close it will display all the details into a list box

If i just bind the custArray to the combobox it displays `name:address:phoneNo:comment:custNo` as i set it out, but like i said i want only the name so how do i separate the name from each Customer entry in the array ??

Any help you be awesome and thanks in advance !!!

Comment: As you yourself hinted at, you should use the [slice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#slice()) method of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you want to set the labelField property on the combobox.  This specifies the field in the source data objects to use in the label.

```
<s:ComboBox dataProvider="{custArray}" labelField="name"/>
```

Comment: I guess I was too busy typing and didn't notice your answer :) Leaving mine as I added a few extra details... but the OP should accept this, since you did it first :)

Comment: No prob - I just had the advantage of three minutes on you!  I like your answer since it does have more info.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Bill Turner, but it hasn't changed the displayed information in the combobox, it still displays all 5 fields side by side in the drop-down menu, and not filtering the name field.

Comment: @Bill Turner as you can see from reading follow ups to this question i hadn't put enough code for the labelField to work, but after fixing the code it does now work again thanks for taking the time to reply in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox has several ways to specify what it should use as the "label" for each item in the `dataProvider`:

- By default, if the elements in the `dataProvider` has a property named `label`, and that property contains a `String` it will display that value.
- `ComboBox` has a [labelField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#labelField) property that you can use to tell it where to find the "label" for each item. In your case, you could set the `labelField` to "name"
- `ComboBox` has a [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#labelFunction) property that allows you to use a function (that you write) to specify what text should be displayed for each item.

I suggest using the the `labelField`, as that seems the most straight forward in this case:

```
<s:ComboBox dataProvider="{custArray}" labelField="name" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sunil D, but it hasn't changed the displayed information in the combobox, it still displays all 5 fields side by side in the drop-down menu, and not filtering the name field.

Comment: @SteveAndrews Hmm, maybe you should show the code you're using to instantiate the `ComboBox`. Does it look like what Bill Turner and I have suggested? Are you using a custom skin for the `ComboBox` (that declares it's own item renderer for the ComboBox's drop down list)?

Comment: `<s:ComboBox id="cboExisting" width="407" dataProvider="{custArray}" labelField="name" fontSize="15"/>` that is the combobox i'm using. [link](http://gyazo.com/3f41efba06c6b0a5ead1518eee02525a) this is a screenshot of the Air app working and the output with all 5 fields.

Thank you for your help as well to all who are helping me

Comment: Could anyone else help with this too, kinda pulling my hair out, as it's a little frustrating (as coding sometimes is) :)

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that possibly your `Customer` class has a toString() or some other method that is returning that text. I realized when you experience the problem that Bill Turner and I both suspected, it usually prints "[Object] Object" for each item,. So you must have some code somewhere that is making it print that.

Comment: Yes your right, in the class definition i do have a toString returning it exactly like it displays. So how would i go about changing that ??

Comment: would it be as simple as removing the toString from the constructor ??

Comment: Well, you could modify the `toString()` function so it returns the proper text. Or delete the toString() method. But something is not right. I just reproduced what you're seeing (the output of toString() is used), but if I do `labelField="name"` in my `ComboBox` it works properly. So not sure why your case is different...

Comment: D really?? damn maybe somewhere else i have an error or put something in where it shouldn't be, because i'm new to programming in general it's harder to spot the errors

Comment: It all makes sense now based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016328/398606) to another question of yours... Your Customer class doesn't have a getter method for the "name" property, so doing `labelField="name"` doesn't work and the ComboBox just uses the value from the `toString()` method instead. If you add the getter method for `name`, then the `labelField` approach should work.

Comment: Sweet that is now working woohoo Thank you so much @Sunil for taking the time to answer my question, and continuing help