# How to define an object in actionscript 3 using a custom class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Hi my problem is i have to be able to reference certain fields inside my Customer object.]

I am studying AS3 at the moment and being taught custom classes, but we are taught to use the `toString` method of returning a value i guess you could call it, what i need is to be able to call one field to identify the object i.e. `name` field from the object in the array, here's my code

```
package valueObjects
{
public class Person
{
    //instance variables
    protected var name:String;
    protected var address:String;
    protected var phoneNo:String;   

    public function Person(n:String,a:String,p:String)
    {
        name=n;
        address=a;
        phoneNo=p;
    }

    public function toString():String
    {
        //returns string 
        return name+":"+address+":"+phoneNo;
    }
}
```

}

some reason it will not put that whole block of code together like [THIS IS](http://gyazo.com/b9c3e972968bf357eb797e2df95e5d38)

So now how do i define it not toString but in object form ??

Comment: If you're trying to access the `name`, `address` and `phoneNo` vars from a different class, then you need to define them as `public`, not `protected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is access the `name`, `address` and `phoneNo` vars from a different class?

If so, you have to declare them as `public` vars instead of `private` vars.

```
public var name:String; //now this can be accessed from other classes:  thisClassInstance.name
```

If you want to have them read-only from other classes, you have to use a getter method:

```
protected var name_:String;  //local var name for full access;
public function get name():String {
    return name_; //this can be access by doing  thisClassInstance.name
}
```

Comment: @Steve Andrews this explains the problem you are having in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16986018/398606). Your `Customer` class only has a `toString()` method, and no way of accessing the individual properties of `name`, `address`, and `phoneNo`. If you add getter methods (as shown here) for each of these properties, then you should be able to do `<s:ComboBox labelField="name" />` as well as access these properties individually (ie: `customer.phone`)

Comment: @LondonDrug thank you for you help, i've got it displaying the name field only

Comment: & @Sunil thank you for you help too in this and the other post of mine, i've got it displaying the name field only